# Django: Firefox doesn't use the loaded CSS

Tags: css, django, firefox, mod-wsgi, django-staticfiles

So basically there's a Django app, that refers external CSS like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="†ext/css; charset=utf-8" href="{% static 'css/basic.css' %}"/>
```

This is rendered in the following way, that seem to be correct:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="†ext/css; charset=utf-8" href="/static/css/basic.css"/>
```

The problem is that the Firefox doesn't use the CSS file, while Chrome and Safari do. When I try to view the CSS file directly in the Firefox it is shown normally and the content type (from `Page Info` box) is `text/css`. Also, when loading the HTML page, the console shows, that the `.css` file was loaded with status 200. In the same time JS files seem to work normally. Any ideas why CSS isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What happens if you try to surf directly against the stylesheet in the browser? http://localhost:8000/static/css/basic.css

2) Remove the type, it isn't needed and might be the thing that confuses Firefox but not other browser.

3) Remove the meta tag. It's meant for the HTML page you're on, not for related files.

Comment: Wow, it's working after I removed the type, but is it obviously safe to omit? It seems that I haven't seen the examples, where it is not present.

Comment: @id256: Have a look at this simple HTML5 example, that's all you need nowadays: http://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/

Comment: I see, so is it HTML5-only feature?

Comment: Well, HTML5 is actually just a description of how browsers work today, so saying that something is a HTML5-feature is like saying that it's something that works in all browsers. So it works everywhere, if that's what you want to know :) Try it!